# How can I open windows applications like notepad and paint using flutter windows desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

How can I open windows applications from my app, like notepad and paint using flutter windows?

```
Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 120,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Notepad",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a button and I want to launch notepad when use clicks it. How can I obtain that functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use [start](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Process/start.html) or [run](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Process/run.html) function from [Process](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Process-class.html) class included in `dart:io` package.